# GNU make: Makefile Build Multiple .cpp Files at Once

Tags: c++, makefile

This is more of a specific question on a specific case.

Here is what I have:

```
SRC = \
  CartoCursor.cpp \
  CartoOperatorFactory.cpp \
  CurveHelper.cpp \
  $(NULL)

CXX = g++
CC_FLAGS = -fPIC -Wall
SYMB_OBJ_DIR = ./obj/symb_obj
SYMB_X_INCLUDE = -I../../../MYLIBS
SYMB_X_OBJS = $(SRC:%.cpp=$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

all : libSymbolXLib.a

libSymbolXLib.a : $(SYMB_X_OBJS)
        rm -f $@


$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(SYMB_X_INCLUDE) -o $(INT_DIR)/$*.o $?
```

When I run this I am getting the following error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `obj/symb_obj/CartoCursor.o', needed by `libSymbolXLib.a'.  Stop.
```

What do I need to do to get the libSymbolXLib to recognize the generic build rule?

If this is not clear please let me know.

---

**UPDATE**

Using:

```
CXX = g++
CC_FLAGS = -fPIC -Wall
SYMB_OBJ_DIR = ./obj/symb_obj
SYMB_X_INCLUDE = -I../../../MYLIBS
SYMB_X_OBJS = $(SRC:%.cpp=$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

all : libSymbolXLib.a

libSymbolXLib.a : $(SYMB_X_OBJS)
        ar rcs $@ $^

$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(SYMB_X_INCLUDE) -o $@ $

[mehoggan@hogganz400 Core]$ make
mkdir -p ./libs
mkdir -p ./obj/symb_obj
make -f ./Graphic/SymbolXLib/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mehoggan/arcgis-new/GraphicsCore_Dev/Runtime/Core'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `obj/symb_obj/CartoCursor.o', needed by `libSymbolXLib.a'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mehoggan/arcgis-new/GraphicsCore_Dev/Runtime/Core'
make: *** [build_symbol_x_lib] Error 2
[mehoggan@hogganz400 Core]$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
[mehoggan@hogganz400 Core]$ uname -a
Linux hogganz400.esri.com 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mehoggan@hogganz400 Core]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)
[mehoggan@hogganz400 Core]$
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `./` prefix on `SYMB_OBJ_DIR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `CartoCursor.cpp` exists in the directory where you run Make.

Also accordingly to [Paul's Rules of Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html) you should modify recipe of `$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp` to update the file with exact name of the target, that is:

```
$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(SYMB_X_INCLUDE) -o $@ $^
```

### UPD.

The same applies to recipe for `libSymbolXLib.a`, it must update the target file. You can insert a `touch $@` stub for debugging, or as @sehe has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673577/545027) add a proper recipe:

```
libSymbolXLib.a : $(SYMB_X_OBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks a lot like the `INT_DIR` and $? variables used is out of place. I'd expect this:

```
$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(SYMB_X_INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
```

You'll want to update the ar rules for libSymbolXLib.a to be something else than just `rm` too :)

The following example worked just fine on my system:

```
SRC = \
      CartoCursor.cpp \
      CartoOperatorFactory.cpp \
      CurveHelper.cpp \
      $(NULL)

CXX = g++
CC_FLAGS = -fPIC -Wall
SYMB_OBJ_DIR = ./obj/symb_obj
SYMB_X_INCLUDE = -I../../../MYLIBS
SYMB_X_OBJS = $(SRC:%.cpp=$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

all : libSymbolXLib.a

libSymbolXLib.a : $(SYMB_X_OBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^

$(SYMB_OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(SYMB_X_INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
```

Demo:

> $ **`touch CartoCursor.cpp CartoOperatorFactory.cpp CurveHelper.cpp`**
>   $ **`mkdir -pv obj/symb_obj`**
>   $ **`make`**
>
> ```
> g++ -c -fPIC -Wall -I../../../MYLIBS -o obj/symb_obj/CartoCursor.o CartoCursor.cpp
> g++ -c -fPIC -Wall -I../../../MYLIBS -o obj/symb_obj/CartoOperatorFactory.o CartoOperatorFactory.cpp
> g++ -c -fPIC -Wall -I../../../MYLIBS -o obj/symb_obj/CurveHelper.o CurveHelper.cpp
> ar rcs libSymbolXLib.a obj/symb_obj/CartoCursor.o obj/symb_obj/CartoOperatorFactory.o obj/symb_obj/CurveHelper.o
> ```
>
> $ **`file libSymbolXLib.a`**
>
> ```
> libSymbolXLib.a: current ar archive
> ```

Comment: added full demo, fixing a typo